# Upload failed : Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to upload my apk file to Google Play. It gives me this message:

> Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htstl.png).

My [build.Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKX0l.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload the zipped file you get. Not the apk in the case of Instant apps.

Comment: Please can you Explain, I'm beginner

Comment: It Okeeeey Thaaaaanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally uploaded the symbols.zip instead of the ABB.